# Parsing XML PostHistory.xml from Stack Exchange Data Dump to Data Frame in Databricks

Tags: xml, apache-spark, databricks

I am very beginner level and I try to do some data processing. I have data set from Stack Exchange Dump Set. I want to convert xml files to csv by using pyspark.
I did the following steps in Databricks notebook but I have table fool of nulls.
This is `PostHistory.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<posthistory>

<row ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" Text="Basically, the title says it all: is there anything that definitely confirms that Svidrigailov actually committed murder in _Crime and Punishment?_ By anything, I mean either a nuanced passage I might have missed in the actual book, some sort of letter or manuscript by Dostoyevsky, or something else. " UserId="3" CreationDate="2017-01-18T17:20:34.290" RevisionGUID="29137b21-e2d7-45a0-acfb-7309871e8cab" PostId="1" PostHistoryTypeId="2" Id="1"/>

<row ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" Text="Is there anything that definitely confirms that Svidrigailov actually committed murder in "Crime and Punishment?"" UserId="3" CreationDate="2017-01-18T17:20:34.290" RevisionGUID="29137b21-e2d7-45a0-acfb-7309871e8cab" PostId="1" PostHistoryTypeId="1" Id="2"/>

<row ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" Text="<crime-and-punishment>" UserId="3" CreationDate="2017-01-18T17:20:34.290" RevisionGUID="29137b21-e2d7-45a0-acfb-7309871e8cab" PostId="1" PostHistoryTypeId="3" Id="3"/>

<row ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" Text="It's [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakespeare's_plays#Shakespeare_and_the_textual_problem) that Shakespeare had no part in publishing the text of his own plays - indeed, many of them were only published posthumously. I've read that a significant proportion of his plays came to press by way of actors in his company, hoping to earn a little extra money, stealing copies of his scripts and smuggling them out to publishers. I've also read that the only parts of the scripts published today which were actually written by Shakespeare are the *lines* - not the stage directions, nor the setting descriptions. Unfortunately, I don't have a reliable source for this claim. Is it true? **Do any of the stage directions in modern publications of Shakespeare plays originate from the man himself?**" UserId="17" CreationDate="2017-01-18T17:25:47.547" RevisionGUID="136be093-d66b-4d40-844f-57b73c71631a" PostId="2" PostHistoryTypeId="2" Id="4"/>
```

I have this library installed on Databricks cluster : com.databricks:spark-xml_2.12:0.10.0

This is what I wrote:

```py
schema_posthistory = StructType([StructField("ContentLicense", StringType()),\
                            StructField("CreationDate", TimestampType()), \
                            StructField("Id", IntegerType()), \
                            StructField("PostHistoryTypeId", IntegerType()), \
                            StructField("PostId", IntegerType()), \
                            StructField("RevisionGUID", StringType()),\
                            StructField("Text", StringType()), \
                            StructField("UserId", IntegerType()), \
                            StructField("UserDisplayName", StringType()), \
                            StructField("Comment", StringType()) ])

PostHistoryDF = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml") \
 .option("rowTag", "row") \
 .option("charset", "UTF8") \
 .schema(schema_posthistory) \
 .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true") \
 .load("/FileStore/tables/PostHistory.xml")
```

This gives me empty table..

[image]

In jupyter notebook I tried the following code and it worked for some of the other files, but for `PostHistory.xml` I have errors. I think it reads some signs (*,_) as separate attributes. I tried to get read of it during creating DF but it seems it didn't work. Also during parsing it creates 7 columns instead of 10.

```py
def dict_fun(root):
    root_attrib = root.attrib
    for tab in root:
        tab_dict = deepcopy(root_attrib)
        attrib_dict = {}
        attrib_dict.update(tab.attrib)
        for key, value in attrib_dict.items():
            attrib_dict.update({key:value})
        tab_dict.update(attrib_dict)
        yield tab_dict

for frame in ['Badges','Comments','PostHistory','PostLinks','Posts','Tags','Users','Votes']:
    link = os.path.join("./LiteratureXML/" + frame) 
    linkcsv = os.path.join("./LiteratureCSV/" + frame)
    tree = et.parse(link + '.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    tab_list = list(dict_fun(root))
    df = spark.createDataFrame(tab_list)
    df = df.replace("\\n", " ")
    df = df.replace("\\r", " ")
    df = df.replace("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", " ")
    df.write.csv(linkcsv + ".csv", sep="|")
    df = spark.read.csv(linkcsv + ".csv", sep="|")

schema_posthistory = StructType([StructField("ContentLicense", StringType()),\
                            StructField("CreationDate", TimestampType()), \
                            StructField("Id", IntegerType()), \
                            StructField("PostHistoryTypeId", IntegerType()), \
                            StructField("PostId", IntegerType()), \
                            StructField("RevisionGUID", StringType()),\
                            StructField("Text", StringType()), \
                            StructField("UserId", IntegerType()), \
                            StructField("UserDisplayName", StringType()), \
                            StructField("Comment", StringType()) ])

PostHistory_df = spark.read.format("csv") \
  .schema(schema_posthistory) \
  .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") \
  .option("header", "false") \
  .option("sep", "|") \
  .load("LiteratureCSV/PostHistory.csv")
```

I am out of ideas how to fix it, can anyone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you try reading the xml file without specifying the explicit schema and see if it reads correctly or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of issues that I see in your code based on how you are trying to read a xml file.

**Data Issue :**

1. There are double quotes in the values for the second record in text attribute as `"Crime and Punishment?"` you will have to remove this double quotes from here and replace that with single quote for the below code to work.
2. There is lessthan(<) sign in the value of the attribute Text for the third record as `<crime-and-punishment>`. you will have to remove that < and > signs/symbol also and then the below code would run perfectly for you.

**Code Issues :**

First of all your xml data do not contains attributes `UserDisplayName` and `Comment` based on the sample xml data that you have posted in the question.

Other thing is that in the explicit schema that you are providing to read the xml file trying appending `_`(underscore) in front of all column names. After doing this you will be able to see the data in the dataframe. you will have to remove `_` from all the column header after you read the xml file by applying some transformations which I will show in below code.

Third you can also read the xml file without specifying the schema and you should get the same output with `_` in the column headers.

```
#explicit schema with _ in column names
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema_posthistory = StructType([StructField("_ContentLicense",StringType()),\
            StructField("_CreationDate", TimestampType()), \
            StructField("_Id", LongType()), \
            StructField("_PostHistoryTypeId", LongType()), \
            StructField("_PostId", LongType()), \
            StructField("_RevisionGUID", StringType()),\
            StructField("_Text", StringType()), \
            StructField("_UserId", LongType())
#reading the xml file                                 ])
PostHistoryDF = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml") \
.option("rowTag", "row") \
.option("charset", "UTF8") \
.option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true") \
.schema(schema_posthistory) \
.load("/FileStore/tables/PostHistory.xml") 
#renaming all columns to remove _
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
renamed_df = PostHistoryDF.select([col(colnames).alias(colnames.replace('_', '')) for colnames in PostHistoryDF.columns])
renamed_df.show()
```

You can also read the xml file without specifying the schema explicitly. but for that also you will have to rename the columns to remove `_` from the column names.

```
PostHistoryDF = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml") \
.option("rowTag", "row") \
.option("charset", "UTF8") \
.option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true") \
.load("/FileStore/tables/PostHistory.xml")
#same stuff to rename the columns to remove _
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
renamed_df = PostHistoryDF.select([col(colnames).alias(colnames.replace('_', '')) for colnames in PostHistoryDF.columns])
renamed_df.show()
```

Comment: Thank you Nikunj! In the end I followed your suggestion and used inferschema, then renamed columns, it turned out perfect :)